# Getting the max value from a list of columns by their index in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with a variety of columns, but the key part of data I am looking to extract is in columns which are named using datetime values which hold a floating point number for currency.

I am basically just looking to find the max value of any column that is of a date value (i.e. 2021-01-15 00:00:00) per row. I originally used list() to try find any column with '-' in but guessing due to the format I can't directly reference the datetime values?

Example
df:

```
index, ID, Cost, 2021-01-01 00:00:00, 2021-01-08 00:00:00, 2021-01-15 00:00:00
0, 1, 4000, 40.50, 50.55, 60.99
0, 1, 500, 20.50, 80.55, 160.99
0, 1, 4000, 40.50, 530.55, 1660.99
0, 1, 5000, 40.50, 90.55, 18860.99
0, 1, 9000, 40.50, 590.55, 73760.99
```

Comment: What is expected output from sample data?

Comment: you can select using numpy, `df.loc[:, [np.issubdtype(dtype, np.datetime64) for dtype in df.dtypes]]`

Comment: Hoping to get the max per row, so a new column would be added for each row containing the maximum float point value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the 'date' columns using a list comprehension which will return the columns that contain `/`. Then you can use `max(axis=1)` to create the column which will show the highest value per row, of your date like columns:

```
date_cols = [c for c in list(df) if '/' in c]
df['max_per_row'] = df[date_cols].max(axis=1)
```

prints:

```
   index  ID  Cost  ...  08/01/2021 00:00  15/01/2021 00:00  max_per_row
0      0   1  4000  ...             50.55             60.99        60.99
1      0   1   500  ...             80.55            160.99       160.99
2      0   1  4000  ...            530.55           1660.99      1660.99
3      0   1  5000  ...             90.55          18860.99     18860.99
4      0   1  9000  ...            590.55          73760.99     73760.99
```

Comment: `df.filter(like='-').max(axis=1)` ? It is better here.

Comment: Thanks @Jez. Is ```filter``` generally preferred than list comprehension when both can be used for the same task?

Comment: Yop, `filter` is more preferable in pandas solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) for select all columns without first 2:

```
df['new'] = df.iloc[:, 2:].max(axis=1)
```

If need select float columns use [`DataFrame.select_dtypes`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html):

```
df['new'] = df.select_dtypes('float').max(axis=1)
```

For columns with `-` use [`DataFrame.filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html):

```
df['new'] = df.filter(like='-').max(axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks, how could I create a new column from this containing the value of any columns which have the datetime in the column name but a floating point integer?

Comment: @nootskej- answer was edited.

Comment: I think you need ```df.filter(like='/')```  because your code returns empty.

Comment: @sophocles - depends of data, OP in question say about `-`, so why do you think `/` ?

Comment: Oh apologies! I thought it was ```/```, on mine it's ```/```.

Comment: @sophocles - I think OP change `/` to `-` if there was `-`